# Unable to boot into Windows after accidentally deleting Ubuntu partition

Tags: grubrescue, grub-efi

I had windows 10 installed on my pc and I installed Ubuntu 17.10 alongside windows. I logged into windows and EasUs partition manager showed me I have some free space and file system of that partition is unknown. Then I went to disk management from My Computer and it showed me that previously mentioned 60GB was empty. So I just deleted that partition and extended another partition. Then I restarted my PC and it's stuck in the "error:no such partition" screen.

I flushed supergrub2 into my pendrive from another PC and restarted my pc with that pen drive. I still can't get my pc to boot. I've seen some YouTube tutorials and tried the "set" command in grub rescue. The result I have is below which does not match any of the tutorials that I've watched.

cmdpath=(hd0,msdos1)/EFI/BOOT
prefix=(hd0)/boot/grub
root=hd0

And typing ”ls” in grub rescue shows the following:

(hd0) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1) (hd1,msdos7) (hd1,msdos6) (hd1,msdos5) ) (hd1,msdos2) (hd1,msdos1)

How can I access Windows or my hard disk again?

Comment: Since you have deleted Ubuntu, grub can't find the files it needs for booting. Either boot on Ubuntu live media to reintall Ubuntu, or boot on Windows media to repair MBR / UEFI. If Windows was installed under UEFI, you might also be able to choose boot order and boot into windows that way.

Comment: If partitions are msdos, then your Windows install has to be the old BIOS/MBR configuration. And then the only way to boot is thru MBR. So you need to restore a Windows boot loader to MBR. Always best to do that before deleting any partitions. Use your Windows repair disk & its repair console to do fixMBR or from Ubuntu live installer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on/422023#422023

Comment: I just followed the link provided by oldfred and was able to boot into my windows. Thanks a lot